# How To Find All Possible Permutations From A Bag under apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, combinations, permutation

i'm trying to find all combinations possible using apache pig, i was able to generate permutation but i want to eliminate the replication of values  i write this code  :

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS f1:chararray;
DUMP A;
('A')
('B')
('C')
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS v1;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS v2;
D = CROSS B, C;
```

And the result i obtained is like :

```
 DUMP D;
('A', 'A')
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'A')
('B', 'B')
('B', 'C')
('C', 'A')
('C', 'B')
('C', 'C')
```

but what i'm trying to obtain the result is like bellow

```
DUMP R;
('A', 'A')
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('B', 'B')
('B', 'C')
('C', 'C')
```

how can i do this? i avoid to use comparison of characters because it's possible to have multiple occurrences of a string in more than a line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can FILTER D to remove the rows you don't want. For example

```
A = load 'testdata.txt';
B = foreach A generate $0;
C = Cross A, B;
D = filter C by $0 <= $1;
dump D;
```

which prints out

```
(C,C)
(B,C)
(B,B)
(A,C)
(A,B)
(A,A)
```

when 'testdata.txt' has

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: but is this works when testdata.txt is like ???
`A
B
C
A`.
There is a possibility to have multiple occurrence of letters.

Comment: You can get rid of dups using DISTINCT. After load do A = DISTINCT A;

Comment: i dont wanna get the value as unique because i will calculate the average for each permitation so i need to keep the redundancy

Comment: Then keep the reference to the original. That is something like `A_all = load ...; A = DISTINCT A_all;` compute the permutations as above and do whatever you need to do on the original dataset with `A_all`

Comment: can you be more clear about what to do? first i load the data in a relation A then i get a second relation B that i will cross with, third step is to cross the two relation so i obtain `C = CROSS A,B`. Where should i insert a distinct relation ????

Comment: `A_all = load 'testdata.txt'; A = DISTINCT A_all;
B = foreach A generate $0;
C = Cross A, B;
D = filter C by $0 <= $1;
dump D;`

Comment: works as i needed, when testing i realise that the relation with distinct does not change anything to the results, so we can remove it, correct me if i'm wrong. Can you explain this code, specially the relation D? Considering as column `A = (1, 1, 2)` B will also be `B = (1, 1, 2)` and `C = ( (1,1), (1,1), (1,2), (1,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,1), (2,2) )` when applying D i expect to have `D = (1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)` which is what i was expecting to get, what i really get is `D = (1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)` which is correct, please explain me,how did you lose (1,1)?